# Suggestions for interesting PI calculation

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

This is a personal interest project that has come to a dead-end. I'm looking for comments and suggestions.

Looking for interesting ways to calculate PI, I seem to have take an approach similar to the one for [Viète's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula). I've come up with this extensible expression:

$${pi} \approx {2}^{3}\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$$
$${pi} \approx {2}^{4}\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$$
$${pi} \approx {2}^{5}\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}$$
$${pi} \approx {2}^{6}\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}}$$

As a programmer, this form has the very interesting term ${2}^{n}$, which may point to a possible efficient bitwise implementation, but the recursive roots are obviously not good. I would like to convert this form into a series but this is where my mathematical knowledge has hit its limits.

So, some questions:

- Does this form exist already?
- Is it worth exploring more?
- If so, can you suggest methods I can research?

I see a similar form appear in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773973/convergence-of-the-series-sum-limits-n-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-cdots-sqrt2), but it doesn't help me move forward, I believe.

Comment: You can look at other sequences for pi [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/Pi/06/)

Comment: This is much more efficient: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Brent-SalaminFormula.html